# media query is not zooming properly

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am trying to use a media query to make my site zoom out (get smaller) when a device with width < 800px visits it. Unfortunately it is not doing anything as far as I can tell. I have the query in the  section. My main CSS stylesheet is linked above that. Here is the relevant CSS:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cah.css" media="screen" />
<style>
@media all and (max-width: 800px) {
  html {
    zoom: 0.8;
    zoom: 80%;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
  }
}
</style>
</head>
// my site
</html>
```

My full site can be found [here](https://cardsagainstoakbank.tk). I am mainly concerned about Chrome but supporting other sites is a nice bonus. I got this code from another Stack Overflow question because I am still learning. Thanks.

Comment: It's working properly...

Comment: @CodeGator are you sure? An older version (with the same proportion but with no media query) is available at 139.99.197.26:8080/test. This version looks exactly the same as the current when I resize my browser to less than 800px. This indicates to me that the zoom is not applying (as there's no change).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I'm just an idiot. I was testing by changing my window height, forgetting that I wrote width.